# How init.rc setprop works

Tags: android, properties, init

I have android 8 from nxp and using it on sabresd board.
I am trying to change dpi settings through setprop settings
So I have put this iside init.${hardware}.rc on boot event

```
# Set the density to 160dpi, default 128dpi is not good
# Set the density to 128 dpi for 480x800, 7 inch.
 setprop ro.sf.lcd_density 128
```

The device works fine and if I do this

```
wm density
Physical density:128
```

Now I put this dpi setting in kernel command line

```
androidboot.sf.lcd_density=128
```

but I do not see device to be in 128 dpi setting. Also

```
wm density
Physical density:160
```

Now this baffles me.Who gave 160dpi settings?

1. How putting setprop in init.$hardware.rc affects the display but not in kernel command line.
2. Who really processes setprop.
   I tried putting prints like this

   on boot
   exec /system/bin/echo "Trigger test E"

I saw nothing, so does that mean boot event never happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android framework there is a file called

[display file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/DisplayMetrics.java)

that contains default dpi if none is specified.

This file have this setting,

```
public static final int DENSITY_MEDIUM = 160;
```

Which is used if no dpi is specified.